# How to upload file in Mojolicious like CGI Perl?

Tags: perl, csv, upload, mojolicious

I have a problem when using `Mojo::Upload` it is not the same as uploading CGI file perl.
I need to read the lines in the CSV file uploaded, with the below code of CGI, it can work!

```
my $upfile = $cgi->param('file');
my $originhead;

while(my $line = <$upfile>){
    $originhead = $line if($first_count == 0);
    $first_count++;
}
```

$originhead = 'id, abc, cda' it is ok

For Mojo, it doesn't work

```
use Mojo::Upload;
my $upfile = $self->req->upload('file');

 my $originhead;

    while(my $line = <$upfile>){
        $originhead = $line if($first_count == 0);
        $first_count++;
    }
$originhead = null  fail
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For CGI, that doesn't work either. Did you mean `$cgi->upload($file)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Mojo::Upload](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Upload) docs. Mojo::Upload is not a filehandle; to read the contents of the uploaded file, the easiest way is to use the `slurp` method, or if you really want to read it line by line, you can convert it to a File asset and retrieve the handle from that.

```
use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious::Controller';

sub action {
  my $self = shift;
  my $upfile = $self->req->upload('file');
  my $contents = $upfile->slurp;
  my $originhead = (split /^/, $contents)[0];

  # or
  my $file = $upfile->asset->to_file;
  my $handle = $file->handle;
  my ($originhead, $first_count);
  while (my $line = <$handle>) {
    $originhead = $line unless $first_count;
    $first_count++;
  }
}
```

To parse a CSV, [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) is usually much simpler than alternatives.

```
use Text::CSV 'csv';
my $array_of_hashes = csv(in => \$contents, headers => 'auto', encoding => 'UTF-8') or die Text::CSV->error_diag;
```

Or for line-by-line processing:

```
my $csv = Text::CSV->new({binary => 1, auto_diag => 2});
binmode $handle, ':encoding(UTF-8)' or die "binmode failed: $!";
$csv->header($handle);
while (my $row = $csv->getline_hr($handle)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think this answer will work, but before that I found a solution for myself! thank you